# Calling doFirst on an Android Plugin Task

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to call the doFirst of a specific Plugin Task but I am not sure if its even possible? If it is, what is the right way of doing it? I tried the following

```
LibraryTask.doFirst {
     /*Do Something*/
     println "HELLO WORLD!!!"
}
```

But no luck. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I get the following error,

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GradleTest'.
> Could not find property 'LibraryTask' on com.somepackage.SomeJavaPluginExtension_Decorated@793aac5f.
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get? "LibaryTask" needs to be the name of the task not the type. Maybe you need to defer the configuration and put it in afterEvaluate{} block.

Comment: @ReneGroeschke: I have added the error in the question. I didnt get what you mean ? can you please elaborate it for me. Sorry if the question doesnt make much sense. I am new to Gradle and learning.

Comment: Are you trying to call the task inside an extension? Could not find **property** `LibraryTask' on com.somepackage.SomeJavaPluginExtension_Decorated@793aac5f`. Make sure you have the above task's `doFirst` used at `project` level.

Comment: Its on project level and no its not a property. However this is going to be a plugin Task that Ill be calling to change some value in a file before this runs.

Comment: I assume that there is no "LibraryTask" at all. do you see that task when running `gradle tasks --all`. In which context do you put that snippet above. As I can see from the error message it's not on root level in your build.gradle file.

Comment: LibraryTask is just an example. How about if you can provide me an example on attaching a task with Andorid plugin task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following worked under buildTypes,

```
buildTypes {
       debug { /*...*/ }
       release {/* ... */ }

       applicationVariants.all { variant ->
             // Do Something
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to be sure from your genericised example but I think your problem is that (unlike standard Gradle) you need to account for Android variants. See the [Manipulating Tasks](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Manipulating-tasks) section of the android plugin user guide

So you probably want to do something similar to

```
android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
        variant.libraryTask.doFirst{
         ....
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. Is this going to work with any plugin? or is it android related only? As I am using a third party plugin.

Comment: Nope that didnt worked. This works for andorid, however this wont work for a specific plugin. If I were to use it in a section of a different plugin I think I will have to change it to something else?